# I'm having difficulty accommodating larger than usual screens. Would really appreciate some advice

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

When applying background-size:100%; to a header image, when viewed on larger screens, the image is cut off. I'm wondering how I can accommodate screen sizes that I don't even have available to me to test on. I am using media queries for certain breakpoints combined with other techniques in attempt to make a fully responsive site. A friend with a much larger screen shared a screen shot and things are broken. So how can I be accommodating for screens I don't even have at my disposal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have same problem, I have a screen from the old 1280x1024 resolution and sometimes my design goes to hell in big screens. There are many applications to test different resolutions, but I recomended [Screenfly](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/). If your desktop doesn't support higher resolutions this is your option ;) You can customize the sizes px by px or test in common resolutions.